# Oculus Quest 2 - Android Device is not responding on Unity on Macbook Pro - Make sure USB debugging has been enabled

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, oculusquest

I build my first VR app using unity. I am getting the following error when trying to build and run on a connected Oculus Quest 2 device!

> Android device is not responding!  Make sure USB debugging has been
> enabled and that the device has authorized this computer. Check your
> device, in most cases there should be a small icon in the status bar
> telling you if the USB connection is up.

**I have tried many different ways to get this working, I am not able to figure this out, is there anything else I can try? I have listed down things I tried and config I have!**

- I have developer mode ON.
- When I connect USB to Macbook Pro I do get an option to Allow in oculus quest with the following message and I select "Allow":

> Allow Access to data, the connected device will be able to access
> files on this headset. [Deny] [Allow]

- I see my Oculus quest device in the "Run Device" dropdown in build settings and have it selected.
- I also installed [Android File Transfer](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/) and I do see all folders and files on the quest 2 device.
- I tried a factory reset and restarting the quest 2 device and my MacBook pro multiple time.
- App I have built runs fine when I click the play button and also it works when I build for the macOS and run on Macbook pro.

Screen shot for the settings and error ***File > Build Settings***

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Quick question, have you gotten the prompt asking to trust your Mac on your Android phone? Even with USB debugging enabled, without that specific prompt it will not allow the connection. You mentioned a prompt to allow the quest but nothing about the phone. To force it to show up, you can try to download [Android File Transfer](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/) to your mac. After opening it, it will force the prompt to come up on your phone.

Comment: I have already downloaded the android file transfer and it shows all folders and files on Oculus quest 2 devices! I don't have an Android phone but I am trying to run the app on Oculus quest - that is where I get the prompt `Allow Access to data, the connected device will be able to access files on this headset.` and I do select Allow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working after I installed the android platform tools.

1. Install android-platform-tools

```sh
brew install android-platform-tools
```

2. Reconnect the USB to Oculus Quest 2 device, this time in oculus I got 2 confirmation boxes! One of them has my laptop address and also the checkbox to remember. I selected Allow.
3. After that `File > Build and Run` is now working all fine!

It required to have other updates to the settings but after I installed adb I did get the 2 confirmations in the quest when I connected and now the build and run functionality works all fine!

Answer (score 1):

I am also developing Quest with Macbook, on Mac OS Unity, you have to install it via terminal with below command.

```
adb install -r /Users/username/Documents/yourProjects/your.apk
```

Otherwise, you have to install bootcamp Win10 for debugging via Quest Link mode.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I installed adb and tried now then I get the actual confirmation to allow and the build and run works fine! I don't even need to run the command in the terminal!

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Android platform tools and Xcode(wrong) and more, it did't worked, additional software is no needed. I have uninstalled all that, and uninstalled the unity version with unity hub and installed again following official tutorial steps and it worked like a charm! https://learn.unity.com/course/create-with-vr?uv=2020.3
Maybe a module was missing or something but I was going crazy for two days. Hope it helps!!
MacBook Air M1, Unity 2020.3.32f1, Blender, Oculus Quest 2.